# hype_mailchimp always creates null campaign, id not found

Tags: php, symfony, mailchimp

I am using hype_mailchimp to create a campaign By MailChimp service.
I ma using symfony2 and my controller code is As,

```
$mc = $this->get('hype_mailchimp');
$data = $mc->getCampaign()->create('regular', array(
        'list_id' => '4a74c85872',
        'subject' => 'test created subject',
        'from_email' => 'mnish.shah@kivite.com',
        'from_name' => 'Mnish Shah',
        'to_name' => 'mnishshah'
            ), array(
        'html' => '<h5>Html content</h5>',
        'sections' => array(),
        'text' => 'test',
        'url' => 'http://www.example.com',
        'archive' => 'test'
    ))->send();
```

The **Error shows Error: Call to a member function send() on a non-object**

means `$data`  remains null always.

pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the create method does not return an object with the send method.

Looking at the read me examples, sending the campaign needs to call `getCampaign` first so it looks like you need to do it as 2 seperate requests.

https://github.com/AhmedSamy/HypeMailchimpBundle

Comment: i did the same also but result was same

Comment: i got the exact problem .here campaign ID does not found.Any help